# how to redirect a photo url to a new photo address in apache and php

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

In apache web server i want to make a special url . that each user request for it get its own photo ? how is possible with Url rewriting ?

or if it is possible through php code ?

For example i want a url like this :

```
http://www.test.com/profileImage.png
```

when each user request for it get his own profile photo .

user 1 gets
    http://www.test.com/user1.png

user 2 gets
    http://www.test.com/user2.png

and so on ....

Comment: Well as Apache will not know which user is requesting their profile image, you will have to do this somewhere that does. Probably PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user opens `www.test.com/profile-image.png` you should internally rewrite that to a PHP script which reads the user's id and determines which image to use. You can then simply include it and set the content type to image/png.